# How do I write cursor which is passed to other sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have one `select` statement which gives me following result

```
MasterID   Date
123        2012-10-15 00:00:00.000
124        2012-12-03 00:00:00.000
453        2012-01-07 00:00:00.000
```

`(output is having 1999 rows)`

Now I need to pass this output to one scalar value function gives takes parameters like

```
MyCalculationFunction (@masterID,@date,@previousdate)
```

I want to pass above values to `MyCalculationFunction` so that I can only select the function and see the all values for each `masterID`

also I need to provide `previousdate` there as parameter.

so please help me to create any cursor which I can use.

Comment: you don't want to pass the result set to the function, you want to call the function in the select. Abandon the concept of cursors.

Comment: Ok please tell me how can I achieve my task ? i'm new to sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT  myCalculationFunction
                (
                masterId,
                [date],
                LAG([date]) OVER (ORDER BY [date])
                )
FROM    mytable m
ORDER BY
        [date]
```

In earlier versions:

```
SELECT  myCalculationFunction
                (
                masterId,
                [date],
                (
                SELECT  TOP 1
                        [date]
                FROM    mytable mi
                WHERE   mi.[date] < m.[date]
                ORDER BY
                        mi.[date] DESC
                )
                )
FROM    mytable m
ORDER BY
        [date]
```